# Android Manifest default launcher issues

Tags: android, manifest

I think I have a strange issue,

I'm redesigning one of my apps and I've defined my issue down to my manifest (I think)

Manifest I have issue with:

```html
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >

        <service
            android:name="com.android.test.WiFi.MessageService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <activity android:name=".Front"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>...
```

Manifest that works fine:

```html
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <service
            android:name="com.android.test.WiFi.MessageService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.android.test.WiFi.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

When changing my Launcher activity to .Front Im unable to see any messages coming into my ChatActivity but when I have .MainActivity set as my Launcher activity it works fine, below is my ChatActivity XML file:

```html
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/messageList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/writeZone"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/app_background" ></ListView>
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/writeZone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/app_background" >
        
     <EditText 
         android:id="@+id/editMessage"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="5"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
         android:maxLines="4"
         android:hint="@string/enter_text"/>
     <Button 
         android:id="@+id/sendMessage"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="2"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:text="@string/send_button"
         android:background="@drawable/button"
         android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
 
 </LinearLayout>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
package com.android.test.WiFi;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.test.WiFi.AsyncTasks.SendMessageClient;
import com.android.test.WiFi.AsyncTasks.SendMessageServer;
import com.android.test.WiFi.CustomAdapters.ChatAdapter;
import com.android.test.WiFi.Entities.Image;
import com.android.test.WiFi.Entities.MediaFile;
import com.android.test.WiFi.Entities.Message;
import com.android.test.R;
import com.android.test.WiFi.Receivers.WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver;
import com.android.test.WiFi.util.ActivityUtilities;
import com.android.test.WiFi.util.FileUtilities;

public class ChatActivity extends Activity {
 private static final String TAG = "ChatActivity"; 
 private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
 private static final int TAKE_PHOTO = 2;
 private static final int RECORD_AUDIO = 3;
 private static final int RECORD_VIDEO = 4;
 private static final int CHOOSE_FILE = 5;
 private static final int DRAWING = 6;
 private static final int DOWNLOAD_IMAGE = 100;
 private static final int DELETE_MESSAGE = 101;
 private static final int DOWNLOAD_FILE = 102;
 private static final int COPY_TEXT = 103;
 private static final int SHARE_TEXT = 104;
 
 private WifiP2pManager mManager;
 private Channel mChannel;
 private WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
 private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
 private EditText edit;
 private static ListView listView;
 private static List<Message> listMessage;
 private static ChatAdapter chatAdapter;
 private Uri fileUri;
 private String fileURL;
 private ArrayList<Uri> tmpFilesUri;
 
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
  
  mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        mReceiver = WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver.createInstance();
        mReceiver.setmActivity(this);
        
        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        
        //Start the service to receive message
        startService(new Intent(this, MessageService.class));
        
        //Initialize the adapter for the chat
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageList);
        listMessage = new ArrayList<Message>();
        chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(this, listMessage);
        listView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
        
        //Initialize the list of temporary files URI
        tmpFilesUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        
  //Send a message
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendMessage);
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMessage);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if(!edit.getText().toString().equals("")){
     Log.v(TAG, "Send message");
     sendMessage(Message.TEXT_MESSAGE);
    }    
    else{
     Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Please enter a not empty message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   }
  });
        
        //Register the context menu to the list view (for pop up menu)
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
 }
 
 @Override
 protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  ActivityUtilities.customiseActionBar(this);
 }
 
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);        
        
  mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
     
   @Override
   public void onSuccess() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Discovery process succeeded");
   }
   
   @Override
   public void onFailure(int reason) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Discovery process failed");
   }
  });
  saveStateForeground(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        saveStateForeground(false);
    }    
    
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  AlertDialog.Builder newDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  newDialog.setTitle("Close chatroom");
  newDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this chatroom?\n"
    + "You will no longer be able to receive messages, and "
    + "all unsaved media files will be deleted.\n"
    + "If you are the server, all other users will be disconnected as well.");
  
  newDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    clearTmpFiles(getExternalFilesDir(null));
    if(MainActivity.server!=null){
     MainActivity.server.interrupt();
    }  
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); 
   }
   
  });
  
  newDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dialog.cancel();
   }
  });
  
  newDialog.show();
 }
    
    @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onStop();
  clearTmpFiles(getExternalFilesDir(null));
 }

 // Handle the data sent back by the 'for result' activities (pick/take image, record audio/video)
    @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  
  switch(requestCode){
   case PICK_IMAGE:
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null) {
     fileUri = data.getData();
     sendMessage(Message.IMAGE_MESSAGE);     
    }
    break;
   case TAKE_PHOTO:
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null) {
     fileUri = data.getData();
     sendMessage(Message.IMAGE_MESSAGE);
     tmpFilesUri.add(fileUri);
    }
    break;
   case RECORD_AUDIO:
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     fileURL = (String) data.getStringExtra("audioPath");
     sendMessage(Message.AUDIO_MESSAGE);
    }
    break;
   case RECORD_VIDEO:
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     fileUri = data.getData();
     fileURL = MediaFile.getRealPathFromURI(this, fileUri);
     sendMessage(Message.VIDEO_MESSAGE);
    }
    break;
   case CHOOSE_FILE:
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     fileURL = (String) data.getStringExtra("filePath");
     sendMessage(Message.FILE_MESSAGE);
    }
    break;
   case DRAWING:
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
     fileURL = (String) data.getStringExtra("drawingPath");
     sendMessage(Message.DRAWING_MESSAGE);
    }
    break;
  }
 }
 
 // Hydrate Message object then launch the AsyncTasks to send it
 public void sendMessage(int type){
  Log.v(TAG, "Send message starts");
  // Message written in EditText is always sent
  Message mes = new Message(type, edit.getText().toString(), null, MainActivity.chatName);
  
  switch(type){
   case Message.IMAGE_MESSAGE:
    Image image = new Image(this, fileUri);
    Log.v(TAG, "Bitmap from url ok");
    mes.setByteArray(image.bitmapToByteArray(image.getBitmapFromUri()));    
    mes.setFileName(image.getFileName());
    mes.setFileSize(image.getFileSize());    
    Log.v(TAG, "Set byte array to image ok");
    break;
   case Message.AUDIO_MESSAGE:
    MediaFile audioFile = new MediaFile(this, fileURL, Message.AUDIO_MESSAGE);
    mes.setByteArray(audioFile.fileToByteArray());
    mes.setFileName(audioFile.getFileName());
    mes.setFilePath(audioFile.getFilePath());
    break;
   case Message.VIDEO_MESSAGE:
    MediaFile videoFile = new MediaFile(this, fileURL, Message.AUDIO_MESSAGE);
    mes.setByteArray(videoFile.fileToByteArray());
    mes.setFileName(videoFile.getFileName());
    mes.setFilePath(videoFile.getFilePath());
    tmpFilesUri.add(fileUri);
    break;
   case Message.FILE_MESSAGE:
    MediaFile file = new MediaFile(this, fileURL, Message.FILE_MESSAGE);
    mes.setByteArray(file.fileToByteArray());
    mes.setFileName(file.getFileName());
    break;
   case Message.DRAWING_MESSAGE:
    MediaFile drawingFile = new MediaFile(this, fileURL, Message.DRAWING_MESSAGE);
    mes.setByteArray(drawingFile.fileToByteArray());
    mes.setFileName(drawingFile.getFileName());
    mes.setFilePath(drawingFile.getFilePath());
    break;
  }  
  Log.v(TAG, "Message object hydrated");
  
  Log.v(TAG, "Start AsyncTasks to send the message");
  if(mReceiver.isGroupeOwner() == WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver.IS_OWNER){
   Log.v(TAG, "Message hydrated, start SendMessageServer AsyncTask");
   new SendMessageServer(ChatActivity.this, true).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, mes);
  }
  else if(mReceiver.isGroupeOwner() == WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver.IS_CLIENT){
   Log.v(TAG, "Message hydrated, start SendMessageClient AsyncTask");
   new SendMessageClient(ChatActivity.this, mReceiver.getOwnerAddr()).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, mes);
  }  
  
  edit.setText("");
 }
 
 // Refresh the message list
 public static void refreshList(Message message, boolean isMine){
  Log.v(TAG, "Refresh message list starts");
  
  message.setMine(isMine);
  
  listMessage.add(message);
     chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     
     Log.v(TAG, "Chat Adapter notified of the changes");
     
     //Scroll to the last element of the list
     listView.setSelection(listMessage.size() - 1);
    } 

 // Save the app's state (foreground or background) to a SharedPrefereces
 public void saveStateForeground(boolean isForeground){
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putBoolean("isForeground", isForeground);
    edit.commit();
 }
 
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat, menu);
        return true;
    }

 // Handle click on the menu
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int idItem = item.getItemId();
        switch(idItem){
         case R.id.send_image:
          showPopup(edit);
          return true;
          
         case R.id.send_audio:
          Log.v(TAG, "Start activity to record audio");
          startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, RecordAudioActivity.class), RECORD_AUDIO);
          return true;
          
         case R.id.send_video:
          Log.v(TAG, "Start activity to record video");
          Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
          takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
          if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                 startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, RECORD_VIDEO);
             }
          return true;
          
         case R.id.send_file:
          Log.v(TAG, "Start activity to choose file");
          Intent chooseFileIntent = new Intent(this, FilePickerActivity.class);
          startActivityForResult(chooseFileIntent, CHOOSE_FILE);
          return true;
          
         case R.id.send_drawing:
          Log.v(TAG, "Start activity to draw");
          Intent drawIntent = new Intent(this, DrawingActivity.class);
          startActivityForResult(drawIntent, DRAWING);
          return true;
          
         default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);         
        }  
    } 
    
    //Show the popup menu
    public void showPopup(View v) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.pick_image:
     Log.v(TAG, "Pick an image");
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
     intent.setType("image/*");
     intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
     
     // Prevent crash if no app can handle the intent
     if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
      startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
        }
     break;
    
    case R.id.take_photo:
     Log.v(TAG, "Take a photo");
     Intent intent2 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     
     if (intent2.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
      startActivityForResult(intent2, TAKE_PHOTO);
        }        
        break;
    }
    return true;
   }
  });
        popup.inflate(R.menu.send_image);
        popup.show();
    }
    
    //Create pop up menu for image download, delete message, etc...
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
        
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        Message mes = listMessage.get((int) info.position);
        
        //Option to delete message independently of its type
        menu.add(0, DELETE_MESSAGE, Menu.NONE, "Delete message");
        
        if(!mes.getmText().equals("")){
         //Option to copy message's text to clipboard
            menu.add(0, COPY_TEXT, Menu.NONE, "Copy message text");
            //Option to share message's text
         menu.add(0, SHARE_TEXT, Menu.NONE, "Share message text");
        }        
        
        int type = mes.getmType();
        switch(type){
         case Message.IMAGE_MESSAGE:
          menu.add(0, DOWNLOAD_IMAGE, Menu.NONE, "Download image");
          break;
         case Message.FILE_MESSAGE:
          menu.add(0, DOWNLOAD_FILE, Menu.NONE, "Download file");
          break;
         case Message.AUDIO_MESSAGE:
          menu.add(0, DOWNLOAD_FILE, Menu.NONE, "Download audio file");
          break;
         case Message.VIDEO_MESSAGE:
          menu.add(0, DOWNLOAD_FILE, Menu.NONE, "Download video file");
          break;
         case Message.DRAWING_MESSAGE:
          menu.add(0, DOWNLOAD_FILE, Menu.NONE, "Download drawing");
          break;
        }
    }
    
    //Handle click event on the pop up menu
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case DOWNLOAD_IMAGE:
             downloadImage(info.id);
                return true;
                
            case DELETE_MESSAGE:
             deleteMessage(info.id);
             return true;
             
            case DOWNLOAD_FILE:
             downloadFile(info.id);
             return true;
             
            case COPY_TEXT:
             copyTextToClipboard(info.id);
             return true;
             
            case SHARE_TEXT:
             shareMedia(info.id, Message.TEXT_MESSAGE);
             return true;
             
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    
    //Download image and save it to Downloads
    public void downloadImage(long id){  
     Message mes = listMessage.get((int) id);
     Bitmap bm = mes.byteArrayToBitmap(mes.getByteArray());     
     String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
     
     FileUtilities.saveImageFromBitmap(this, bm, path, mes.getFileName());
     FileUtilities.refreshMediaLibrary(this);
    }
    
    //Download file and save it to Downloads
    public void downloadFile(long id){
     Message mes = listMessage.get((int) id);
     String sourcePath = mes.getFilePath();
        String destinationPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
        
        FileUtilities.copyFile(this, sourcePath, destinationPath, mes.getFileName());
        FileUtilities.refreshMediaLibrary(this);
    }
    
    //Delete a message from the message list (doesn't delete on other phones)
    public void deleteMessage(long id){
     listMessage.remove((int) id);
     chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    
    private void clearTmpFiles(File dir){
     File[] childDirs = dir.listFiles(); 
     for(File child : childDirs){
      if(child.isDirectory()){
       clearTmpFiles(child);
      }
      else{
       child.delete();
      }
     }
     for(Uri uri: tmpFilesUri){
      getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
     }
     FileUtilities.refreshMediaLibrary(this);
    }
    
    public void talkTo(String destination){
     edit.setText("@" + destination + " : ");
     edit.setSelection(edit.getText().length());
    }
    
    private void copyTextToClipboard(long id){
     Message mes = listMessage.get((int) id);
  ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
  ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("message", mes.getmText());
  clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
  Toast.makeText(this, "Message copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    
    private void shareMedia(long id, int type){
     Message mes = listMessage.get((int) id);
     
     switch(type){
      case Message.TEXT_MESSAGE:
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
          sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mes.getmText());
          sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
          startActivity(sendIntent);
     }     
    }
}
```

Also my run Log:

```
D/ViewRootImpl@ebb4fca[ChatActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage    processPointer 0
- D/ViewRootImpl@ebb4fca[ChatActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage    processPointer 1
- V/ChatActivity: Send message
- V/ChatActivity: Send message starts
- V/ChatActivity: Message object hydrated
- V/ChatActivity: Start AsyncTasks to send the message
- V/ChatActivity: Message hydrated, start SendMessageClient AsyncTask
- V/SendMessageClient: doInBackground
- V/InputMethodManager: Starting input:    tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@2caaec4 nm :       com.android.test       ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@12451ad
- I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner -    mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
- V/SendMessageClient: doInBackground: connect succeeded
- V/SendMessageClient: doInBackground: send message succeeded
- D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=71
- D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=75
- V/SendMessageClient: onPostExecute
```

Currently when I set .Front as my main activity to launch at first I navigate to ChatActivity.java I try and send a message within my app (Its a Wifi chat app) it doesnt display what I've sent and it doesnt display what I've recieved,

When I switch what Activity launches first to MainActivity.java I navigate to ChatActivity.java in the app and when I send messages I can see them,

I'm confused as to why this is happening?

Comment: `Im unable to see any messages coming into my ChatActivity ` What do you mean ??

Comment: You have to add more useful details, if you want to get help here!

Comment: @AtefHares I've added as much as I can